# Is it okay to use lexical negation of mathematical terms?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Like?:

- An **abnormal** subgroup
- Connected/Path-connected/Compact/Metrizable locally but not **globally**
- An **irregular** space (It's okay to call a polyhedron irregular, but what about a space?)
- An **abnormal** space
- An **incompletely** regular/normal/metrizable space
- An **imperfectly** normal space
- **Complicatedly** connected

Comment: Generally, yes. But when in doubt, just include a definition in your writing ("We say an abnormal subgroup is a subgroup that is not normal").

Comment: Does "incompletely regular" mean "regular but not completely regular" or does it just mean "not completely regular"?

Comment: @bof The former.

Comment: Then what do you call a space whch is not completely regular? "Completely irregular" won't do.

Comment: @bof "non-Tychonoff" will do it, if the space is Fréchet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say some of these are okay. The preferred way to negate mathematical adjectives seems to be to add the prefix "non-" even when English antonyms exist. Thus,

- non-normal
- non-regular
- non-Hausdorff

Your use of the word "global" in the context of connectedness or compactness would seem redundant. "Incompletely" and "Imperfectly" seem a little too clever. "Complicatedly" is a mouthful, and if it's supposed to mean the negation of "simply connected" then there's already a term for that: "multiply connected". (The pairs "simple/multiple" and "ordinary/singular" are common.)

In general, you want your writing to be understood. Use the existing language if available, or have a good reason to reject it, and always define your terms. Non-native speakers of English (or whatever discourse language you're writing in) may not be as familiar with the more uncommon modes of negation or pairs of antonyms.

Comment: What would the negation of "path-connected" be? "non-path-connected" or "path-non-connected"?

Comment: Of those two, certainly "non-path-connected". Another option, perhaps preferable, would be "path-disconnected".